# Angular Formly - Combining nested forms with repeating sections

Tags: angular-formly

So this should be pretty simple, I just want to combine a repeating section within a nested form using Formly.

There are examples for doing each of these individually but I cannot find any examples that combine these functions.

**Repeating Section**
http://jsbin.com/murule/32/edit?js,output

**Nested Forms**
http://jsbin.com/zaqeke/22/edit?js,output

I would be very appreciative of anyone who could help!

An example would awesome if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`Repeating Section` is a complex example of `Nested Form`

You can see in `repeatSection.html` repeater `ng-repeat="element in model[options.key]"`

`<div class="repeatsection" ng-repeat="element in model[options.key]" ng-init="fields = copyFields(to.fields)">
    <formly-form fields="fields"
        model="element"
        form="form">
    </formly-form>
    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="model[options.key].splice($index, 1)"> Remove </button>
    </div>`